# FFT analysis of signals that were combined

Tags: fft, discrete-signals

I have a dataset with ECG artefacts, noise and EMG activations. Now I want to analyse the EMG activation using Welch's and Burg's method. The EMG realizations are approximately 0.25 s long, resulting in a very poor frequency resolution. My idea was to paste several EMG realizations together and make a Welch of it.

However, is this a problem as there would be a jump between different segments resulting in false high frequency components? Or how could I tackle this problem in another matter, without using any of the more complicated preprocessing methods(template subtraction, wavelet decomposition etc)

Comment: Sounds interesting but I am not familiar with this domain. Could you describe your approach/problem more explicit using plain dsp terminology?

Comment: I think that’s a valid idea and concern. To get rid of edge effects you could try some windowing and overlap. Are you familiar with this method?

Comment: You are going to run into problems with phase though…

Comment: The EMG activations have a varying length N, but are all aproximately the same length. Furthermore, the assumption is that the frequency content will not change within one recording (~5 min), due to physiology time response. I did indeed use windowing and overlap, but then the windowing function will be between parts that might run in to some phase problems. However, I came across the Allan Deviation, but I'm unsure if that will help me in my case